# Is Filesystem relevant in SFTP?

Tags: ntfs, nas, sftp, filezilla, ext4

I have a home server with an NTFS disk attached, and I use FileZilla to access the data on that disk. I have both Linux and Windows clients, and I was wondering if the data would still be accessible from Windows clients if the disk was formatted to ext4 (since it is not accessed directly)?

Comment: I'm not specifically knowledgeable about ext4 and its compatibility (or incompatibility) with Windows, but it occurs to me that that there might be a minor issue if Linux clients create files on the server whose names contain characters that aren't allowed in Windows filenames (``\``, `:`, `*`, `?`, `"`, `<`, `>`, and `|`). (Of course `/` isn't allowed in a _filename_ on either OS.) It shouldn't be a serious problem, but you might need to explicitly specify a local filename (e.g., `get foo:bar foobar` rather than just `get foo:bar`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not relevant.

The clients are getting the files via the (S)FTP protocol, not by file-system calls to the server.

So as long as your chosen (S)FTP server software can read the file system that holds the files you're serving out the clients will behave the same way, as they are still interfacing with the server in the same way (via SFTP).